# Number of ways to make first move

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, combinatorial-game-theory

Alice and Bob are playing a game. They have N containers each having one or more chocolates. Containers are numbered from 1 to N, where ith container has A[i] number of chocolates.

The game goes like this. First player will choose a container and take one or more chocolates from it. Then, second player will choose a non-empty container and take one or more chocolates from it. And then they alternate turns. This process will continue, until one of the players is not able to take any chocolates (because no chocolates are left). One who is not able to take any chocolates loses the game. Note that player can choose only non-empty container.

The game between Alice and Bob has just started, and Alice has got the first Chance. She wants to know the **number of ways to make a first move such that under optimal play, the first player always wins.**

Example : Let their are 2 containers and chocolates in each container are : [2 3]

Then here answer is 1 as Only 1 set of moves helps player 1 win.

```
Player:      1      2      1      2      1
Chocolates: 2 3 -> 2 2 -> 1 2 -> 1 1 -> 0 1
```

Comment: This game is called Nim.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim

Comment: @DarthGeek I know game is called Nim .But i need to COUNT THE WAYS.Its something different

Comment: Once you know the winning condition, simply count all the way to obtain that winning condition from the first move.

Comment: You can read the strategy in the wiki. There is only one possible move that ensures victory (if the first possition was a winning position). The algorythm would tell Alice to "remove $n$ chocolates from a container with $m$ chocolates. The amount of winning moves at any given point is that of the containers with $m$ chocolates.

Comment: @Gina Please explain.Am not getting it

Comment: FYI, Nim questions have shown up a number of times on MSE. This question is likely similar enough to represent a duplicate of them.

Comment: I think @Ginna is counting the moves from the winning condition 'till the end of the game. That is not what you are asking, right?

Comment: @DarthGeek Hey for 3 containers with [1 1 1] the answer is 3.

Comment: @Semiclassical I think its different from a NIM game as i am supposed to count the ways

Comment: Exactly, the winning algorythm tells you to "remove n chocolates from a container with m chocolates in it". In this case, the algorythm tells you to remove 1 chocolate from a container with 1 chocolate in it. Since there are 3 containers, there are 3 ways. But essentially is the same move.

Comment: Also, this very same question has already been asked. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/868102/number-of-ways-to-win-chocolate-game?rq=1

Comment: @DarthGeek Yeah perhaps the question is same.But i didnt get the answer provided..